# control child action with or without parent's action

Tags: cocos2d-x

When parent do any action, its children do same action also. But sometimes, I don't want child do the action. For example, a sprite like a man have a blood bar, when it moving, the bar should moving along with man also, that's OK. But when I shake or rotate the man, the bar should do nothing.

So, is a simple way to control it? The only one way I though is remove those child from parent, after action complete, re-add them.

Answer (score 0):

you can control each child action using its separate tag.when ever you define child then set its tag and after when you want to get action of particular child then get child `[self getActionByTag:childTag];`  and perform action on it.

Comment: seems not what I am asking. my question is how to disable the action act on child when their parent run that action

Answer (score 0):

- As you said removing and reattaching to another node works.
- Or don't make that bar as child of man and add it to another node ,handle actions for that separately.
- I don't think that there is any way to make child static and move only parent.